# Calling an array of structures inside a structure using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++

I'm trying to reference a structure (which is also an array ) inside a structure using pointer arithmetic,

The structures are these:

```
struct Team
{
    int name;
    int **games;
};

struct Championship
{
    Team *teams;
    unsigned int size;
};

Championship *c;
c= new Championship;
c->teams= new Team[2];
```

I've tried using [] to reference the position of the array and it works just like so:

```
int i=0;(Just as an example)
c->teams[i].name;
```

It even works for the matrix inside the Team structure :

```
c->teams[i].games[i][i];
```

But I don't know how to implement this using pointer arithmetic since doing something like:

```
c->(teams+i);
```

Gets me an error saying:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token
error: 'teams' was not declared in this scope
```

How should I use pointer arithmetic for this structure?

Comment: Just *don't* use pointer arithmetic when you want to access memory as an array. It's sometimes hard to get right, could be harder to read and understand, and is also more to write.

Comment: But to help you, the pointer it `c->teams` (in full) and you need to use `c->teams + i` to get a pointer ti the `i`:th element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c->teams` is a pointer to the first element of the array. If you want `i`th element do either of these:

```
(c->teams)[i]
*(c->teams + i)
```

Both are exactly the same by definition.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this as C++, so **just don't use raw pointers**. Use proper C++ libraries:

```
struct Team {
  ..
};

struct Championship {
  std::vector<Team> teams;
};
```

This is safer, shorter, with proper allocation and deallocations. In practice it's best under all aspects compared to using raw pointers.

Your code requires more caution in everything, it lacks memory allocation and deallocation (which should be done in constructors and not like you are doing), it's basically C code.

If you need to share pointers then you can use `std::unique_ptr<T>` for single ownership or `std::shared_ptr<T>` as needed.